# Flux: Higher order components to set up store listeners

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

Following this article [Mixins Are Dead. Long Live Composition](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750), I've set up a Pet component listening to pet and owner stores user a higher order component. But how would one pass an owner_id from the pet resource into `connectToStores`? Is this simply a case where mixins are superior?

```
Pet = connectToStores(Pet, [PetStore, OwnerStore], (props) => {
  return {
    pet   : PetStore.getOne(props.id),
    owner : OwnerStore.getOne(ownerId), // this should come from pet.owner_id                                        
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `PetStore.getOne` synchronous? Just assign the result to a variable.

```javascript
Pet = connectToStores(Pet, [PetStore, OwnerStore], (props) => {
  var pet = PetStore.getOne(props.id);

  return {
    pet   : pet,
    owner : OwnerStore.getOne(pet.owner_id),    
  };
});
```

If it's not synchronous, your store will need to emit a change event to cause the component to re-render when the pet is available. The component will also somehow need to handle the pet being unavailable.

```javascript
Pet = connectToStores(Pet, [PetStore, OwnerStore], (props) => {
  var pet, loaded, owner;

  pet = PetStore.getOne(props.id);
  if (pet) {
    loaded = true;
    owner = OwnerStore.getOne(pet.owner_id);
  } else {
    loaded = false;
    owner = null;
  }

  return {
    pet    : pet,
    owner  : owner,
    loaded : loaded
  };
});
```